# No success with accessing an iframes content via ".content()"

Tags: jquery, dom, iframe

http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Supposedly, you are able to access an iframes DOM via the contents() method.
I've cut and pasted the code, chnaged the id to the iframe on my page, and going for a very simple div, the only one in the iframe. It doesnt find it. I've successfully managed to manipulate the css of the iframe itself, so I'm pretty sure everything is correct.
It's also all in a document ready conditional.

The page in question is here http://syndex.me/tagged/belgium

Hope someone can shed some light on this methods workings.

Thanks

```
$("#tumblr_controls").css({
   position : 'fixed',
   top : 'auto',
   bottom : '15px',
}); //works
$("#tumblr_controls").contents().find("div").css("right","auto"); //doesnt work
$("#tumblr_controls").contents().find("div").css("left","0"); //doesnt work
```

Please note you have to be logged into tumblr in order to see the controls in question I believe.

```
<iframe src="http://assets.tumblr.com/iframe.html?10&amp;src=http%3A%2F%2Fsyndex.me%2F&amp;lang=en_US&amp;name=syndex&amp;brag=0" scrolling="no" width="330" height="25" frameborder="0" style="right: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-style: initial; border-color: initial; background-color: transparent; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; position: fixed; top: auto; bottom: 15px; z-index: 1000007; " id="tumblr_controls">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off">
        <link rel="icon" href="http://assets.tumblr.com/images/favicon.gif?2" type="image/gif">
 </head>
    <body style="background-color:transparent; margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="var image1 = new Image(); image1.src = 'http://assets.tumblr.com/images/iframe_like_alpha.png';
    var image2 = new Image(); image2.src = 'http://assets.tumblr.com/images/iframe_like_active_alpha.png';">

    <style>
        img {
            margin-left: 3px;
        }
    </style>

    <div style="position:absolute; top:3px; right:3px; white-space:nowrap; height:20px;">

<form action="/follow" method="post" style="display:block; float:left;" onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Iframe', 'Follow', 'syndex');">
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="4d9WHkMln7qxbqRkkU1FJ51jYk">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="syndex">
                            <input type="image" src="http://assets.tumblr.com/images/iframe_follow_alpha.png?663" style="width:58px; height:20px; border-width:0px; display:block;
                            margin-left:3px; cursor:pointer;" alt="Follow">
                        </form>

            <a target="_top" href="http://www.tumblr.com/dashboard"><img src="http://assets.tumblr.com/images/iframe_dashboard_alpha.png?663" alt="Dashboard" style="height:20px;
            width:81px; border-width:0px; display:block; float:left; cursor:pointer;"></a>

                        </div>

</body></html>

</iframe>
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have permission to access the contents of the `tumblr_controls` frame because it comes from another domain.

Further info:

- http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes
- http://www.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/

Comment: That would be a good reason. Someone wants to add some content to your answer, btw.

Comment: so is a subdomain considering a different domain? Also, i'm on syndex.me, but it's all tumblr. Would i be correct in thinking then that if i went to syndex.tumblr.com it would work? Although going there automatically reroutes me to syndexme anyway.

Comment: Also why does it not throw errors in the console then? Seems unusual.

Comment: @RGBK - The [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) means that to access another document/script with Javascript, it needs to originate from the same domain (subdomain's count, too). But not another domain, and JS has no way (that I know of) of resolving one domain to another as equivalent.